# How to add an attribute with QGIS 2.8.1 Python console?

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

i would like to add an attribute with the python console:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("C:/donnees_SIG/05.shp","nou","ogr")
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
layer.addAttribute(QgsField("STATUT", QVariant.Int))
```

But it doesn't work...
When i write the last line, the python console returns 'False'.

I'm using QGIS 2.8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [Using Vector Layers: Adding and Removing Fields](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#adding-and-removing-fields)

```
res = layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("STATUT", QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields()
```